# How to avoid the L in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numbers

```
>>> sum(range(49999951,50000000))
  2449998775L
```

Is there any possible way to avoid the L at the end of number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `L` is just for you. (So you know its a `long`) And it is nothing to worry about.

```
>>> a = sum(range(49999951,50000000))
>>> a
2449998775L
>>> print a
2449998775
```

As you can see, the printed value (actual value) does not have the `L` it is only the `repr` (representation) that displays the `L`

Consult [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

You are looking at a Python literal representation of the number, which just indicates that it is a python `long` integer. *This is normal*. You do not need to worry about that `L`.

If you need to print such a number, the `L` will not normally be there.

What happens is that the Python interpreter prints the result of `repr()` on all return values of expressions, unless they return `None`, to show you what the expression did. Use `print` if you want to see the *string* result instead:

```
>>> sum(range(49999951,50000000))
2449998775L
>>> print sum(range(49999951,50000000))
2449998775
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand that but I really need the actual number.

Comment: It is. Python is leaking an implementation detail you shouldn't worry about.